# required validation does not work with kendo-combobox in angular

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-combobox

I am using Kendo combobox with angular 5 , I am wondering if there is a way to apply some validations on this control, I have tried to use `required` attribute but it did not work, since kendo-combobox does not have property such as `.valid` to check if it is valid or not

```
 <kendo-combobox required #nameInput   [data]="availableCompanies" textField="displayText" valueField="value" [(value)]="company.selectedItem" 
                [filterable]="true"  
                [allowCustom]="true" [valueNormalizer]="valueNormalizer"  >
              </kendo-combobox>
```

Comment: I just ran into a similar issue. It ended up being the model value that was not found in the data entries. The combo box looked like blank but actually the model had a value.

Answer (score 0):

You should use template or reactive [forms](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation) in order to apply validation. Using required validation for the combobox is demonstrated [here](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/combobox/forms/#toc-reactive-forms) for reactive forms.

Answer (score 0):

You can set validation rules to force the a item selection:

```
$("form").kendoValidator({
            rules: {
                invalidSelection: function (input) {
                    if (input.is("[name=COMBO_NAME]")) {
                        if (input.val() != "" && $("#TCOMBO_NAME").data("kendoComboBox").selectedIndex == -1) {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            }
        });
```

This way it travel all the fields of the form, being able to establish rules for each field.
Regards.